# how to install Cloupy on Mac within a Conda envirnoment

Tags: python, installation, pip, conda, spyder

I would like to install [Cloupy](https://github.com/pdGruby/cloupy/tree/main) on MacBook within a Conda Environment.
It gives only instructions with pip3 for Linux system.

What I tried to do is

```
conda activate spyder-geo
```

and

```
pip install cloupy
```

or

```
pip3 install cloupy
```

but I get the following error

```
(spyder-geo) andreacecilia@MacBook-Pro-di-Andrea ~ % pip install cloupy       
Collecting cloupy
  Using cached cloupy-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.0 MB)
Collecting matplotlib<=3.5.1,>=3.4.3
  Downloading matplotlib-3.5.1-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (7.2 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 7.2/7.2 MB 8.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting pandas<=1.3.5,>=1.3.3
  Using cached pandas-1.3.5.tar.gz (4.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting beautifulsoup4<=4.10.0,>=4.9.3
  Using cached beautifulsoup4-4.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
Collecting scipy<=1.7.3,>=1.7.2
  Using cached scipy-1.7.3-1-cp39-cp39-macosx_12_0_arm64.whl (27.0 MB)
Collecting Pillow<=9.0.0,>=8.4.0
  Using cached Pillow-9.0.0-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (2.7 MB)
Collecting requests<=2.27.1,>=2.26.0
  Using cached requests-2.27.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (63 kB)
Collecting numpy<=1.22.1,>=1.21.4
  Using cached numpy-1.22.1-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (12.8 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: pyshp==2.1.3 in ./miniconda3/envs/spyder-geo/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from cloupy) (2.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler==0.11.0 in ./miniconda3/envs/spyder-geo/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from cloupy) (0.11.0)
Collecting pyproj<=3.3.0,>=3.2.1
  Using cached pyproj-3.3.0.tar.gz (217 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [24 lines of output]
      <string>:9: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Users/andreacecilia/miniconda3/envs/spyder-geo/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/Users/andreacecilia/miniconda3/envs/spyder-geo/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/Users/andreacecilia/miniconda3/envs/spyder-geo/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "/private/var/folders/j8/z9z9dhys2sl71vnvnsbgn0780000gn/T/pip-build-env-36cst6x7/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "/private/var/folders/j8/z9z9dhys2sl71vnvnsbgn0780000gn/T/pip-build-env-36cst6x7/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/private/var/folders/j8/z9z9dhys2sl71vnvnsbgn0780000gn/T/pip-build-env-36cst6x7/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 480, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "/private/var/folders/j8/z9z9dhys2sl71vnvnsbgn0780000gn/T/pip-build-env-36cst6x7/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 232, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 160, in get_extension_modules
        File "<string>", line 23, in get_proj_version
        File "/Users/andreacecilia/miniconda3/envs/spyder-geo/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 424, in check_output
          return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
        File "/Users/andreacecilia/miniconda3/envs/spyder-geo/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 528, in run
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '/Users/andreacecilia/miniconda3/envs/spyder-geo/bin/proj' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Maybe it is because it is not correct to use pip within a condo environment, but I don't know what else to do. I use this environment for Spyder.

Answer (score 1):

For pure Python packages already on PyPI, the ideal solution is to [add it to Conda Forge](https://conda-forge.org/docs/maintainer/adding_pkgs.html) by using [`grayskull`](https://conda.github.io/grayskull/index.html). That way, not only you can install it through Conda, but everyone in the future can too!

I've put in [a PR to add it](https://github.com/conda-forge/staged-recipes/pull/24638). For straightforward packages like this, turnaround time is usually within 48 hours. Once that goes through, then one could do:

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge cloupy
```

Though, note that the versions for dependencies for this package are rather narrow (lower + upper bounded), so it may be better to create a new environment for this:

```bash
conda create -n cloupy -c conda-forge cloupy
```

---

For future reference, feel free to tag me directly (GH: **@mfansler**) in any `staged-recipes` submissions. I can help with /review Python, C++, and R recipes.